# why this css transition doesn't work

Tags: css

```
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3 ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
      opacity:0.2;
}

.box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity:1;
}
```

I try to do a transition with opacity, it doesn't work, but it can work if I do the background change effect.

demo http://jsfiddle.net/rsg4e/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rsg4e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
transition: opacity 0.3 ease-out;
```

Instead of

```
transition: background-color 0.3 ease-out;
```

Because on hover you are changing `opacity` not `background`.

```
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3 ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
      opacity:0.2;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/rsg4e/2/)

Comment: what else can I set besides background-color and opacity?

Comment: @user3033162 I am not getting your point. you want to set something other with background,opacity? like height,width ?

Answer (score 3):

**You were on the right track - just went the wrong way.**

### [Fixed your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Be3wN/)

What you wanted was the background-color to change opacity, not the full element and whatever might be inside of it.  All you need to do is set the backgrounds to `rgba()` values and you're set.

```
.box {

  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);

}
.box:hover {

  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);

}
```

*Of course - if you ACTUALLY want everything inside of it to change opacity as well, then go with one of the other answers - they hit it on the head.*

Answer (score 2):

You're setting a transition on the background-color, when you should be calling it on the opacity i.e:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not a `background-color` property to transition because you've specified it as `background`. so naturally the transition wont work.

Change it to :

```
-webkit-transition: background 0.3 ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
```

or

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
```

and your hover state to

```
.box:hover { background: /*younewcolor*/;}
```

and everything should should work fine.

Comment: I don't really wanna down-vote just for this but FYI - `background` incorporates all sub-properties as well (`-color`, `-position`, etc), regardless of where it's called.  You can see this in action on my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Be3wN/

Comment: @Deryck, I was unaware that background incorporates all of the sub-properties! Thanks for teaching me something and for helping rather than downvoting (+1 to your answer since its better than the accepted answer, and I cant give you rep for your comment) .